# Display data in table format from tables that have associations

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I have 3 tables, Jobs, Registration and Skills. The assosciations are a Job has many Registrations, and a registration belongs to a job. A registration has many skills and a skill belongs to a job. My db can carry as many as 5 similar skills as long as one person does not have the same skills twice.

*Problem:*
I am trying to render the skills one person has in a table format like this:
[image: Table format]

I grouped the applicants according to the jobs they were both applying for on the template `dashboard.ex` like this

```
<%= for {k,v} <- sort_by_job() do %>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="8"><%= k %></td>
    <%= Enum.map(v, fn applicant -> %>
    <td>
      <tr>
        <td><%= applicant.name %></td>
        <td><%= applicant.email %></td>
        <td><%= applicant.website %></td>
        <td><%= applicant.cover_letter %></td>
      </tr>
    </td>
      <% end) %>
```

The `sort_job` function being called is on the view (dashboad.ex) and it returns the names of the people in each job category. The code is

```
def sort_by_job() do
  Enum.group_by(
   Applications.get_all_applicants(),
   fn applicant -> applicant.jobs.name end
  )
end
```

As I said before, skills is on another table and it has registration_id to be able to know which skill belongs to who, how can I render the skills according to each person in the table format?

Answer (score 1):

Is your 'applicant' the same as your `registration`?

You didn't include your actual schemas, but this should give you the general idea:

You can preload the skills that belong to your applications.

```
Application
|> Repo.all()
|> Repo.preload(:skills)
```

In your view, you can handle how to display the skills in your table.  If you just want them to be comma delimited, you can do something like...

```
applicant.skills
|> Enum.map(skill.name)
|> Enum.join(",")
```

Comment: Thanks! I actually got to solve it, had the same idea, but since you can't pipe on the view in elixir I `<%= Enum.map(applicant.skills, fn skill -> <%= skill.name %> end) %> `